# Problem with RDD bash script variable

Tags: bash, rrdtool

I have the folowing bash script i'm trying to implement, but it fails awfully, can anyone help me with some advice...

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE='/var/www/router.rrd'
OUTPUT='/var/www/router.png'
RRDTOOL='rrdtool graph'
$RRDTOOL $OUTPUT \
        -t "192.168.10.1" -v "Time in ms" \
        --start="now-1d" \
        --end="now" \
        --height="120" \
        --width="440" \
        "DEF:ping_time=$FILE:ping:AVERAGE" \
        "CDEF:shading2=ping_time,0.98,*" "AREA:shading2#F90000:router" \
        "GPRINT:ping_time:LAST:Last\: %5.2lf ms" \
        "GPRINT:ping_time:MIN:Min\: %5.2lf ms" \
        "GPRINT:ping_time:MAX:Max\: %5.2lf ms" \
        "GPRINT:ping_time:AVERAGE:Avg\: %5.2lf ms" >/dev/null
```

---

The error mesages are like the folowing

```
hostname:/# sh -v /var/www/router.sh
FILE='/var/www/router.rrd'
OUTPUT='/var/www/router.png'
RRDTOOL='rrdtool graph'
HOST='hello'
: command not foundre_retea/ping/router.sh: line 6:
"$RRDTOOL" $OUTPUT \
: command not foundre_retea/ping/router.sh: line 7: rrdtool graph
        -t "192.168.10.1" -v "Time in ms" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 8: -t: command not found
        --start="now-1d" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 9: --start=now-1d: command not found
        --end="now" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 10: --end=now: command not found
        --height="120" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 11: --height=120: command not found
        --width="440" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 12: --width=440: command not found
        "DEF:ping_time=$FILE:ping:AVERAGE" \
/var/www/router.sh: line 13: DEF:ping_time=/var/www/router.:ping:AVERAGE: No such file or directory
        "CDEF:shading2=ping_time,0.98,*" "AREA:shading2#F90000:router" \
/var/www/monitorizare_retea/ping/100.100.100.6_graph.sh: line 14: CDEF:shading2=ping_time,0.98,*: command not found
        "GPRINT:ping_time:LAST:Last\: %5.2lf ms" \
.... and so on
```

Comment: You know, you could probably help us out by telling us what "fails awfully" means. What error messages are you getting? How does the result differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that it gives you an error that says "command not found". If that's the case it's because you're putting a command and an argument in a variable. Don't do that. Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Additionally, it looks like your script file may have Windows line endings. If that's the case then running `dos2unix` on it will fix that.

```
dos2unix scriptname
```

Another possibility is that you may have white space after your line-continuation backslashes. Removing the white space characters may help:

```
sed 's/\\[[:blank:]]\+$/\\/' scriptname
```